# Organising a 'list of lists' Wiki page into a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to parse as a table the data in the list of lists Wikipedia page at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trees_and_shrubs_by_taxonomic_family

I want to create a table linking the first word of each subheading containing 'family' to the first word each of its main bullet points, so I am not interested in much part of the text.

For an example, I would like an output like this:

```
    Araucariaceae   Agathis
    Araucariaceae   Araucaria
    Cupressaceae    Athrotaxis
```

for a page like this: [sorry, I have enough reputation to post pictures in the Maths StackExchange, but not here]

```
    Gymnosperms
    Conifers
    Araucariaceae: monkey-puzzle family
    Agathis – kauri conifers        
    Agathis australis – kauri pine; dammar
    Agathis lanceolata – red kauri
    Agathis robusta – Dundathu pine; Queensland kauri; smooth bark kauri
    Araucaria – monkey puzzle trees
    Araucaria angustifolia – Paraná pine
    Araucaria araucana – monkey-puzzle tree
    Araucaria bidwillii – bunya-bunya
    Araucaria columnaris – Cook pine
    Araucaria cunninghamii – Moreton Bay pine; hoop pine
    Araucaria heterophylla – Norfolk Island pine
    Araucaria hunsteinii – klinki
    Cupressaceae: cypress family
    Athrotaxis – Tasmanian cedars
    Athrotaxis cupressoides – pencil pine
    Athrotaxis selaginoides – King Billy pine
```

I looked up the wikipediaAPI package, but didn't find anything specific. Is there a function which does something similar?
Moreover, I don't think I can handle so much raw text in a neat way with the str package.

Any advice?

Comment: Pull the list as is, split on strings ending in "family", append the first word of that to every first word until the next string with "family"? Skipping any entries with more than 1 word before the dash would remove the specific plants.

Comment: Another option for this kind of task is to use [OpenRefine](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine). It is set up to do exactly what you are asking through a user interface. I use it when I need to quickly pull a list down and merge it with something I already have in Excel. Here is a tutorial video for [taking a table from Wikipedia and formatting it.](https://youtu.be/cO8NVCs_Ba0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a way with beautiful soup:

First we pull the text we want into a list

```
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trees_and_shrubs_by_taxonomic_family'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

tree = []
for text in soup.find_all(['h4', 'b']):
    tree.append(text.text)
```

Then we do some basic df manipulation, to clean it how we want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tree)
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('–')]
df[1] = df.loc[df[0].str.contains('edit')]
df[1] = df[1].ffill()
df = df[df[0]!=df[1]].reset_index(drop = True).copy()
df[1] = df[1].str.replace(":.*","", regex = True)

df.head()

        0             1
0   Agathis     Araucariaceae
1   Araucaria   Araucariaceae
2   Athrotaxis  Cupressaceae
3   Callitris   Cupressaceae
4   Calocedrus  Cupressaceae
```

Comment: Thanks, I was messily dealing with it as a big string vector, but your code is much neater.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way would be to use the page source (via edit) and use the formatting information to parse it:

```
def do_it(epl):
    for line in epl:
        if ":" in line:
            top = line.split(":")[0][6:].strip("[]")
        elif line.startswith("*'''''"):
            print top, line.split()[0][8:].strip("[]'")
```

- Family lines contain a semi-colon and start with `====[[`
- Those under it start with `*'''''`
- Strip off all the extra formatting characters

Takes the page edit text:

```
====[[Podocarpaceae]]: podocarp family====
----
*'''''[[Afrocarpus]]''''' '''– African podocarps'''
**''[[Afrocarpus gracilior]]'' – musengera; zigba
*'''''[[Dacrycarpus]]''''' 
**''[[Dacrycarpus dacrydioides]]'' – kahikatea
*'''''[[Dacrydium]]''''' 
**''[[Dacrydium cupressinum]]'' – rimu
*'''''[[Podocarpus]]''''' '''– Australasian podocarps'''
**''[[Podocarpus gracilior]]'' – fern pine
**''[[Podocarpus henkelii]]'' – long-leafed yellowwood
**''[[Podocarpus macrophyllus]]'' – kusamaki; inumaki
**''[[Podocarpus neriifolius]]'' – oleander-leaf podocarp
```

and outputs

```
Podocarpaceae Afrocarpus
Podocarpaceae Dacrycarpus
Podocarpaceae Dacrydium
Podocarpaceae Podocarpus
```